# How to list available GNOME bst builds?

Tags: gnome, compiling

The [GNOME build instructions](https://wiki.gnome.org/Newcomers/BuildSystemComponent) explains how to build specified programs, like `gedit` with `bst shell --build core/gedit.bst`. I'd like to get an overview of other possible programs and the prefix which I need to specify (`core/` in this example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Available build targets can be found easily with

```
cd /path/to/gnome-build-meta
find elements/ -name *.bst
```